# How to decide which pre-trained model to use for transfer learning?

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models, transfer-learning

For Deep Learning problems that deal with image data, how do I decide which pre-trained model architecture to use, like VGG or Resnet or Xception instead of trying them all(which will take days to train).

I understand that there is no silver bullet architecture that works for all type of problems, but, I want to gain intuition on which networks to try or consider trying in case of type of data or outcome(e.g.: multi-class, multi-label) or any such thing in general.